# How to get all variable names but only from a specific file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get ALL variables from the file `xyz.js` in order to create an array with those names in `main.js`

Comment: can you show us what xyz.js looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with non-module files, it's just not how JavaScript works.

If you were using JavaScript modules, you could get an object containing all of its exports via:

```
import * as x from "./the-module.js";
```

...but that's specific to modules and their exports.

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. Crowder already noted: you can't just request all the variables from a specific file.

What you could do, is load the file contents and parse it. 
It depends a bit on how the variables are declared in xyz.js.

If you know the variables are all defined with `const` or `let` it should be fairly easy to do. When multiple variables are defined with one `const` of `let` it gets a bit trickier.

The more you know about xyz.js, the easier it is to parse the content and extract the variable names.